# How to change icon and name of Python task?

Tags: python, process, python-multiprocessing

I am currently working on my Python application with multiprocessing. I would like to change the name and icon of my process so that it shows up correctly in the Windows task manager.

I tried like this:

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=task, name="Worker")
process.start()
```

A new process was created in the task manager as desired, but it was still called "Python". However, when I output the process.name variable, I get the correct value returned. Can anyone help me to change the name and icon?

Answer (score 1):

To change the name and icon of a Python process, you can use the [setproctitle library](https://pypi.org/project/setproctitle). This library allows you to change the name of the process and also its icon using the functions `setproctitle` and `setthreadtitle` which can set the current process and thread title like this:

```py
import threading
import setproctitle

def worker(title):
    setproctitle.setthreadtitle(title)
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=('reader',), daemon=True)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=('writer',), daemon=True)
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

You can see the full example [here](https://github.com/dvarrazzo/py-setproctitle/blob/master/tests/setthreadtitle_test.py).

Comment: You could include a link to its documentation/homepage and a small example to show how it works so your answer is helpful to future readers

Comment: I tried with `setproctitle.setproctitle("test")` but the name in the TaskManager was still Python. Also, I haven't figured out how to use setproctitle to change the process icon.